# как выключить hover для элемента на переднем плане?

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, hover

Возможно ли, сделать "прозрачным" в функциональном смысле элемент, при наведении или нажатии мышью на элемент? (без боли и страданий)

Я приведу пример, для svg, но думаю, что он будет актуален и для html.

Например есть прямоугольный полигон. выше него расположена текстовая нода.
При наведении на полигон, у меня есть стиль poly:hover{/**/},который срабатывает.
Но когда мышь наводим на текстовую ноду, которая никак кроме позиции не связана с полигоном, :hover'а мы уже не видим.

конкретный пример структуры:

```
<g id="bildings">               
    <g class="bld">
        <polygon class="f fll-blue" id="b_b21-22_poly" points="339.8,437.4 339.8,435 339.8,434.9 339.8,431.8 334,431.8 334,434.9 317.3,434.9 317.3,431.8 311.7,431.8 311.7,434.9 311.7,435 311.7,440 303.2,440 303.2,438.4 266,438.4 266,450.9 303.2,450.9 311.7,450.9 311.7,450.8 339.8,450.8 339.8,445.4 341.3,445.4 341.3,437.4 "/>
    </g>
    <g class="bld">
        <polygon class="f fll-blue" id="b_b8-9_poly" points="255.6,482.4 255.6,476.9 228.3,476.9 228.3,482.4 228.3,490.9 228.3,493 262.6,493 262.6,490.9 270.7,490.9 270.7,482.4 "/>
    </g>
</g>
<g id="text_group">
    <text class="bilding_label zoom_layer_1" id="b_b21-22_txt" x="288.944117647" y="446.35" fill="#ddd">21-22</text>
    <text class="bilding_label zoom_layer_1" id="b_b8-9_txt" x="240.676470588" y="489.95" fill="#ddd">8-9</text>
</g>
```

[image: Пример]

Вопрос:
Как сделать  прозрачным для наведения курсора, в программном, но не визуальном смысле?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Думаю, это почти подоёдёт:

```
pointer-events: none;
```

http://caniuse.com/#feat=pointer-events

Comment: Спасибо. Это то-что нужно!